# Find the minimum of $x_n$ where $n\in \mathbb{N}^{*}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I denote with $x_n$ the sum of the digits of $2771^n$. I have to find the minimum of $x_n$ where $n\in \mathbb{N}^{*}$.

I computed few terms of the sequence and I think that $x_1$ is the minimum. I notice that $x_n$ should be congruent with $1$ or $8$ modulo $9$. I tried to find an argument why it can't be $8$ or $10$ but I didn't succeed.

Comment: Is this a contest problem from the year $2771$??? How advanced...

Comment: I would be very surprised if this could actually be solved. Does anything speak against  $17$ ?

Comment: $2771^{500} \equiv 1 \pmod{10000}$, that probably leaves us a limited number of cases to deal with.

Comment: Posting as a comment, since there was a negative response to this as an answer but I think it is interesting information for solving this problem. From computing by python the first 2500 terms of this sequence it would seem that your prediction that $x_1$ is the minimum is probably right, which is encouraging, but of course not a proof of anything.

Comment: I would like to generalize to the sum of digits in any base $b$, call it $\,_bx_n$. Then $\,_bx_1$ is always the minimum for any base $b$. In base $2$ the year $2771$ will be $101011010011_2$ whose sum of digits is $7$.

Comment: @NoahSolomon I've found a linear fit $x_n\approx \lfloor 15.486 n-2.916\rfloor$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider $2771^n$ for $n>0$ and let $O$ be the sum of the digits located in odd position. Let $E$ be the sum of the remaining digits. (For $n=1$ we have $O=8,E=9$.) Then

$$O+E\equiv 2771^n \equiv(-1)^n \pmod 9$$
$$O-E\equiv 2771^n \equiv(-1)^n \pmod {11}$$

For a total digit sum of less than 17 we require $O+E=9+(-1)^n$ but then
$$2E\equiv 9\pmod {11} \implies E\ge 10\implies O+E> 10.$$

Therefore the digit sum cannot be less than $17$.

Comment: @Tesla Daybreak. Great spot - thanks!

Comment: No problem! Glad to see that you found an even easier argument.